# Can't open page anymore after initializing type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I wrote a service which takes data from an API. I Followed a tutorial but when I add this part

```
  type: SearchType = SearchType.all;
```

I can't open the page anymore(Tab). So the error might be caused by this part, since it means there is an error when I can't open it. The tutorial I used is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QPbBJgNF94&t=1747s

friends.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SearchType, FriendsService } from '../services/friends.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-friends',
  templateUrl: './friends.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./friends.page.scss'],
})
export class FriendsPage implements OnInit {


  results: Observable<any>;
  searchTerm = '';
  type: SearchType = SearchType.all;


  constructor(private friendsService: FriendsService) { 


  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  searchChanged() {
    this.results = this.friendsService.searchData(this.searchTerm, this.type);
  }

}
```

friends.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';



export enum SearchType {
  all = '',
  movie = 'movie',
  series = 'series',
  episode = 'episode'
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FriendsService {
  url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/'
  apiKey = 'a16a078b';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  searchData(title: string, type: SearchType): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('${this.url}?s=${encodeURI(title)}&type=${type}&apikey=${this.apiKey}')
    .pipe(
      map(results => results['Search'])
    );


  }

  getDetails(id){
    return this.http.get('${this.url}?i=${id}&plot=full&apikey=${this.apiKey}');

  }
}
```

friends.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="favorite">

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

          <ion-list>
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of (results | async)" [routerLink]="['/', 'friends', item.imdbID]">

           {{ item.Title}}

              </ion-item>
        </ion-list>



</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **friends.service.ts** Change this:

```
'${this.url}?s=${encodeURI(title)}&type=${type}&apikey=${this.apiKey}'
```

to this:

```
let t = '' if type === SearchType.any else '&type=${type}'
'${this.url}?s=${encodeURI(title)}${t}&apikey=${this.apiKey}'
```

In HTTP, I wouldn't add a param when it's empty

You may want to look at conditioning s as well. Because if you don't pass anything in title, s= is irrelevant too.

Comment: sorry I don't really get where/how to put it properly into my code. When I just replace it, its red underlined. Could you maybe quickly directly copy into my code please?

Comment: Look.. Try calling the web service in a browser directly. If you have &type= with nothing following it will be an issue. if you have &type=movies you will have no problem. Look at code! In SearchData of FriendService ! Above return add t variable and substitute 't' in the URL instead.

Comment: t will be an empty string if SearchType.any - otherwise allow things like movies.

Comment: I suspect you aren't sharing an appropriate apiKey. But, what do you get if you type this in your browser (substituting the proper key)? Try manually adding the url params and test in browser before you code: http://www.omdbapi.com/?apiKey=a16a078b